# Server is not pinging without domain name

Tags: networking

I am having a server in a VPN network (cannot tell the network name) and I was able to ping it from my system through command prompt like below:

```
c:\> ping servername
```

After a few days, it stopped pinging from my system and later I had to add the domain name to ping the server like below:

```
c:\> ping servername.na.ex.com
```

(na and ex are just sample domain names).

I am not sure why the server stopped pinging just with server name. Any help / idea / inputs on this?

Comment: Is your server still running?

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you connect on the first time the DNS Suffix (na.ex.com) was passed with the DHCP and now it doesn't that why you have to ping the complete name instead of the servername.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found out the issue. The issue was with the DNS search suffix order which is present in properties of IPv4 in network connections.